# Azure maps autocomplete - country and city only

Tags: azure-maps

I am writing an autocomplete service and want to get only country and city calling a Microsoft Azure service - with no addresses and POI or such.

I currently found [Address Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/search/getsearchaddress) where I would need to call https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/address, but it returns addresses, not cities and countries - which leads to many duplicates.

Plus, If I need to have a fixed number of auto complete options - say, 15 - it is going to require multiple calls to the service until I have all 15. On top of that, I will never know if there are more results for a typed partial country/city combination or not.

I don't want to use a fixed list as it needs maintenance.

I would not want to use another data provider for now, if it is possible to achieve with Azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't supported yet, but is planned for the future. The closest that could be done now would be to use the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/search/getsearchaddressstructured service but it requires a country code to be specified, so you would only get cities for the specified country. For example, passing in `new` as the `municipality` as done in the following query:

```
https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/address/structured/json?api-version=1&municipality=new&countryCode=US&subscription-key=<Your_Key>
```

will return the following city results:

- New York
- New Orleans
- New Braunfels
- New Port Richey
- New Bern
- New Haven
- New Iberia
- New Castle
- New Bedford
- New Albany

Here is the raw response

```
{
    "summary": {
        "query": "new",
        "queryType": "NON_NEAR",
        "queryTime": 23,
        "numResults": 10,
        "offset": 0,
        "totalResults": 998,
        "fuzzyLevel": 1
    },
    "results": [
        {
            "type": "Geography",
            "id": "US/GEO/p0/1167",
            "score": 2.6649377346,
            "entityType": "Municipality",
            "address": {
                "municipality": "New York",
                "countrySubdivision": "NY",
                "countrySubdivisionName": "New York",
                "countryCode": "US",
                "country": "United States",
                "countryCodeISO3": "USA",
                "freeformAddress": "New York, NY"
            },
            "position": {
                "lat": 40.71305,
                "lon": -74.00723
            },
            "viewport": {
                "topLeftPoint": {
                    "lat": 40.9175,
                    "lon": -74.25564
                },
                "btmRightPoint": {
                    "lat": 40.49587,
                    "lon": -73.70027
                }
            },
            "boundingBox": {
                "topLeftPoint": {
                    "lat": 40.9175,
                    "lon": -74.25564
                },
                "btmRightPoint": {
                    "lat": 40.49587,
                    "lon": -73.70027
                }
            },
            "dataSources": {
                "geometry": {
                    "id": "d49d86a4-0f4b-45f2-b607-31a84d02af00"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Geography",
            "id": "US/GEO/p0/90711",
            "score": 2.5113995075,
            "entityType": "Municipality",
            "address": {
                "municipality": "New Orleans",
                "countrySecondarySubdivision": "Orleans",
                "countrySubdivision": "LA",
                "countrySubdivisionName": "Louisiana",
                "countryCode": "US",
                "country": "United States",
                "countryCodeISO3": "USA",
                "freeformAddress": "New Orleans, LA"
            },
            "position": {
                "lat": 29.95176,
                "lon": -90.07462
            },
            "viewport": {
                "topLeftPoint": {
                    "lat": 30.21747,
                    "lon": -90.24051
                },
                "btmRightPoint": {
                    "lat": 29.86582,
                    "lon": -89.62506
                }
            },
            "boundingBox": {
                "topLeftPoint": {
                    "lat": 30.21747,
                    "lon": -90.24051
                },
                "btmRightPoint": {
                    "lat": 29.86582,
                    "lon": -89.62506
                }
            },
            "dataSources": {
                "geometry": {
                    "id": "0000554c-4100-3c00-0000-0000596a7628"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Geography",
            "id": "US/GEO/p0/103135",
            "score": 2.4384012222,
            "entityType": "Municipality",
            "address": {
                "municipality": "New Braunfels",
                "countrySubdivision": "TX",
                "countrySubdivisionName": "Texas",
                "countryCode": "US",
                "country": "United States",
                "countryCodeISO3": "USA",
                "freeformAddress": "New Braunfels, TX"
            },
            "position": {
                "lat": 29.70988,
                "lon": -98.11973
            },
            "viewport": {
                "topLeftPoint": {
                    "lat": 29.91293,
                    "lon": -98.34627
                },
                "btmRightPoint": {
                    "lat": 29.59298,
                    "lon": -97.9908
                }
            },
            "boundingBox": {
                "topLeftPoint": {
                    "lat": 29.91293,
                    "lon": -98.34627
                },
                "btmRightPoint": {
                    "lat": 29.59298,
                    "lon": -97.9908
                }
            },
            "dataSources": {
                "geometry": {
                    "id": "9d7bf985-115b-423a-979a-97cc093c3166"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Geography",
            "id": "US/GEO/p0/23041",
            "score": 2.4345231056,
            "entityType": "Municipality",
            "address": {
                "municipality": "New Port Richey",
                "countrySecondarySubdivision": "Pasco",
                "countrySubdivision": "FL",
                "countrySubdivisionName": "Florida",
                "countryCode": "US",
                "country": "United States",
                "countryCodeISO3": "USA",
                "freeformAddress": "New Port Richey, FL"
            },
            "position": {
                "lat": 28.2502,
                "lon": -82.71408
            },
            "viewport": {
                "topLeftPoint": {
                    "lat": 28.33939,
                    "lon": -82.76461
                },
                "btmRightPoint": {
                    "lat": 28.17319,
                    "lon": -82.57478
                }
            },
            "boundingBox": {
                "topLeftPoint": {
                    "lat": 28.33939,
                    "lon": -82.76461
                },
                "btmRightPoint": {
                    "lat": 28.17319,
                    "lon": -82.57478
                }
            },
            "dataSources": {
                "geometry": {
                    "id": "00005546-3300-3c00-0000-000059a7e5e6"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Geography",
            "id": "US/GEO/p0/27115",
            "score": 2.414732933,
            "entityType": "Municipality",
            "address": {
                "municipality": "New Bern",
                "countrySecondarySubdivision": "Craven",
                "countrySubdivision": "NC",
                "countrySubdivisionName": "North Carolina",
                "countryCode": "US",
                "country": "United States",
                "countryCodeISO3": "USA",
                "freeformAddress": "New Bern, NC"
            },
            "position": {
                "lat": 35.10832,
                "lon": -77.04612
            },
            "viewport": {
                "topLeftPoint": {
                    "lat": 35.28085,
                    "lon": -77.26051
                },
                "btmRightPoint": {
                    "lat": 34.90304,
                    "lon": -76.83165
                }
            },
            "boundingBox": {
                "topLeftPoint": {
                    "lat": 35.28085,
                    "lon": -77.26051
                },
                "btmRightPoint": {
                    "lat": 34.90304,
                    "lon": -76.83165
                }
            },
            "dataSources": {
                "geometry": {
                    "id": "00004e43-3300-3c00-0000-0000596be1d9"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Geography",
            "id": "US/GEO/p0/60622",
            "score": 2.4027762413,
            "entityType": "Municipality",
            "address": {
                "municipality": "New Haven",
                "countrySecondarySubdivision": "New Haven",
                "countrySubdivision": "CT",
                "countrySubdivisionName": "Connecticut",
                "countryCode": "US",
                "country": "United States",
                "countryCodeISO3": "USA",
                "freeformAddress": "New Haven, CT"
            },
            "position": {
                "lat": 41.30825,
                "lon": -72.92416
            },
            "viewport": {
                "topLeftPoint": {
                    "lat": 41.35038,
                    "lon": -72.99807
                },
                "btmRightPoint": {
                    "lat": 41.2464,
                    "lon": -72.81773
                }
            },
            "boundingBox": {
                "topLeftPoint": {
                    "lat": 41.35038,
                    "lon": -72.99807
                },
                "btmRightPoint": {
                    "lat": 41.2464,
                    "lon": -72.81773
                }
            },
            "dataSources": {
                "geometry": {
                    "id": "00005543-5400-3c00-0000-0000596911a2"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Geography",
            "id": "US/GEO/p0/90802",
            "score": 2.4020097256,
            "entityType": "Municipality",
            "address": {
                "municipality": "New Iberia",
                "countrySecondarySubdivision": "Iberia",
                "countrySubdivision": "LA",
                "countrySubdivisionName": "Louisiana",
                "countryCode": "US",
                "country": "United States",
                "countryCodeISO3": "USA",
                "freeformAddress": "New Iberia, LA"
            },
            "position": {
                "lat": 30.00256,
                "lon": -91.81698
            },
            "viewport": {
                "topLeftPoint": {
                    "lat": 30.12129,
                    "lon": -91.9944
                },
                "btmRightPoint": {
                    "lat": 29.73782,
                    "lon": -91.65921
                }
            },
            "boundingBox": {
                "topLeftPoint": {
                    "lat": 30.12129,
                    "lon": -91.9944
                },
                "btmRightPoint": {
                    "lat": 29.73782,
                    "lon": -91.65921
                }
            },
            "dataSources": {
                "geometry": {
                    "id": "0000554c-4100-3c00-0000-00005968eae5"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Geography",
            "id": "US/GEO/p0/61589",
            "score": 2.3937933445,
            "entityType": "Municipality",
            "address": {
                "municipality": "New Castle",
                "countrySecondarySubdivision": "New Castle",
                "countrySubdivision": "DE",
                "countrySubdivisionName": "Delaware",
                "countryCode": "US",
                "country": "United States",
                "countryCodeISO3": "USA",
                "freeformAddress": "New Castle, DE"
            },
            "position": {
                "lat": 39.66066,
                "lon": -75.56184
            },
            "viewport": {
                "topLeftPoint": {
                    "lat": 39.7245,
                    "lon": -75.66496
                },
                "btmRightPoint": {
                    "lat": 39.55219,
                    "lon": -75.50945
                }
            },
            "boundingBox": {
                "topLeftPoint": {
                    "lat": 39.7245,
                    "lon": -75.66496
                },
                "btmRightPoint": {
                    "lat": 39.55219,
                    "lon": -75.50945
                }
            },
            "dataSources": {
                "geometry": {
                    "id": "00005544-4500-3c00-0000-000059685073"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Geography",
            "id": "US/GEO/p0/36482",
            "score": 2.3928732872,
            "entityType": "Municipality",
            "address": {
                "municipality": "New Bedford",
                "countrySecondarySubdivision": "Bristol",
                "countrySubdivision": "MA",
                "countrySubdivisionName": "Massachusetts",
                "countryCode": "US",
                "country": "United States",
                "countryCodeISO3": "USA",
                "freeformAddress": "New Bedford, MA"
            },
            "position": {
                "lat": 41.63405,
                "lon": -70.92766
            },
            "viewport": {
                "topLeftPoint": {
                    "lat": 41.74525,
                    "lon": -70.97843
                },
                "btmRightPoint": {
                    "lat": 41.58185,
                    "lon": -70.87872
                }
            },
            "boundingBox": {
                "topLeftPoint": {
                    "lat": 41.74525,
                    "lon": -70.97843
                },
                "btmRightPoint": {
                    "lat": 41.58185,
                    "lon": -70.87872
                }
            },
            "dataSources": {
                "geometry": {
                    "id": "0000554d-4100-3c00-0000-00005969fc6d"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Geography",
            "id": "US/GEO/p0/12185",
            "score": 2.3897461891,
            "entityType": "Municipality",
            "address": {
                "municipality": "New Albany",
                "countrySecondarySubdivision": "Floyd",
                "countrySubdivision": "IN",
                "countrySubdivisionName": "Indiana",
                "countryCode": "US",
                "country": "United States",
                "countryCodeISO3": "USA",
                "freeformAddress": "New Albany, IN"
            },
            "position": {
                "lat": 38.28351,
                "lon": -85.823
            },
            "viewport": {
                "topLeftPoint": {
                    "lat": 38.40435,
                    "lon": -85.8853
                },
                "btmRightPoint": {
                    "lat": 38.22944,
                    "lon": -85.76089
                }
            },
            "boundingBox": {
                "topLeftPoint": {
                    "lat": 38.40435,
                    "lon": -85.8853
                },
                "btmRightPoint": {
                    "lat": 38.22944,
                    "lon": -85.76089
                }
            },
            "dataSources": {
                "geometry": {
                    "id": "00005549-4e00-3c00-0000-0000596b63cf"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi @rbrundritt, do you know if there are any news on the functionality you said had been planned for the future?

Comment: Note yet, but I believe there is plans for a new autocomplete service that includes this that will be added to V2 of the search API. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/search-v2

Comment: I tried GetGeocoding https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/search-v2/get-geocoding?tabs=HTTP and it seems the search is looking for a complete word, not partial - like for typeahead. However, I kept looking and found Fuzzy search https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/search/get-search-fuzzy?tabs=HTTP which looks better. I will need a few days to experiment with different queries and results, but it seems quite flexible as it has typeahead mode and has entityType filter.

Comment: The search v2 Geocoding service expects near complete queries (it will make logical guesses for the input). I believe there are plans for a V2 of the autocomplete service.

Answer (score 0):

There is an end point in the Atlas API which might be closer to what we need - [Fuzzy search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/search/get-search-fuzzy?tabs=HTTP).

It allows to set a typeahead flag and you can filter on entity type, so, for a GET reauest https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/fuzzy/json?api-version=1.0&query=Paris&typeahead=true&limit=3&entityType=Municipality,MunicipalitySubdivision,CountryTertiarySubdivision,CountrySubdivision

with your subscription key in the header

and an example return would be

```
    "summary": {
        "query": "paris",
        "queryType": "NON_NEAR",
        "queryTime": 26,
        "numResults": 3,
        "offset": 0,
        "totalResults": 141,
        "fuzzyLevel": 1,
        "queryIntent": []
    },
    "results": [
        {
            "type": "Geography",
            "id": "FR/GEO/p0/13312",
            "score": 2.5989630222,
            "entityType": "Municipality",
            "address": {
                "municipality": "Paris",
                "countrySecondarySubdivision": "Paris",
                "countrySubdivision": "Île-de-France",
                "countryCode": "FR",
                "country": "France",
                "countryCodeISO3": "FRA",
                "freeformAddress": "Paris"
            },
            "position": {
                "lat": 48.85689,
                "lon": 2.35085
            },
            "viewport": {
                "topLeftPoint": {
                    "lat": 48.90216,
                    "lon": 2.2241
                },
                "btmRightPoint": {
                    "lat": 48.81552,
                    "lon": 2.46991
                }
            },
            "boundingBox": {
                "topLeftPoint": {
                    "lat": 48.90216,
                    "lon": 2.2241
                },
                "btmRightPoint": {
                    "lat": 48.81552,
                    "lon": 2.46991
                }
            },
            "dataSources": {
                "geometry": {
                    "id": "00005858-5800-1200-0000-000077369045"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Geography",
            "id": "US/GEO/p0/119280",
            "score": 2.4116733074,
            "entityType": "Municipality",
            "address": {
                "municipality": "Paris",
                "countrySecondarySubdivision": "Lamar",
                "countrySubdivision": "TX",
                "countrySubdivisionName": "Texas",
                "countryCode": "US",
                "country": "United States",
                "countryCodeISO3": "USA",
                "freeformAddress": "Paris, TX"
            },
            "position": {
                "lat": 33.66143,
                "lon": -95.55632
            },
            "viewport": {
                "topLeftPoint": {
                    "lat": 33.86768,
                    "lon": -95.66163
                },
                "btmRightPoint": {
                    "lat": 33.38955,
                    "lon": -95.31052
                }
            },
            "boundingBox": {
                "topLeftPoint": {
                    "lat": 33.86768,
                    "lon": -95.66163
                },
                "btmRightPoint": {
                    "lat": 33.38955,
                    "lon": -95.31052
                }
            },
            "dataSources": {
                "geometry": {
                    "id": "00005554-3100-3c00-0000-0000596a4495"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Geography",
            "id": "US/GEO/p0/106765",
            "score": 2.4046759605,
            "entityType": "Municipality",
            "address": {
                "municipality": "Paris",
                "countrySecondarySubdivision": "Henry",
                "countrySubdivision": "TN",
                "countrySubdivisionName": "Tennessee",
                "countryCode": "US",
                "country": "United States",
                "countryCodeISO3": "USA",
                "freeformAddress": "Paris, TN"
            },
            "position": {
                "lat": 36.30275,
                "lon": -88.32636
            },
            "viewport": {
                "topLeftPoint": {
                    "lat": 36.42548,
                    "lon": -88.59662
                },
                "btmRightPoint": {
                    "lat": 36.18254,
                    "lon": -88.15962
                }
            },
            "boundingBox": {
                "topLeftPoint": {
                    "lat": 36.42548,
                    "lon": -88.59662
                },
                "btmRightPoint": {
                    "lat": 36.18254,
                    "lon": -88.15962
                }
            },
            "dataSources": {
                "geometry": {
                    "id": "0000544e-3100-3c00-0000-00005969642b"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```